# How to add multiple numbers from Strings then save them

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple budget app and would like to add all inputted income then save this income to use in other classes. I'm lost and not sure how to do it. Here's the portion of my code inside of my onCreate method. I have income and incomeName both as Strings

```
addIncomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //TODO: Transfer this info to line in scroll view showing incomes
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(enterIncomeEditText.getText()) |
                                TextUtils.isEmpty(enterIncomeNamesEditText.getText())) {
                            Toast.makeText(Income.this, "Entry Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            //create income and incomeName strings
                            income = enterIncomeEditText.getText().toString();
                            incomeName = enterIncomeNamesEditText.getText().toString();
                            mLayout.addView( createNewTextView(incomeName + " " + income));
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intent`.
Assume you want to pass all inputted data to Activity B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), ActivityB.class);  
intent.putExtra("income",income);
intent.putExtra("incomeName",incomeName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in Activity B, you can use `getStringExtra()` to get all inputted value.